# Java Arraylist change affect other variables

Tags: java, list, javafx, arraylist, immutability

I am using java fx, nothing fancy in the code below, and catching the text field's focusedProperty to overwrite the newly entered value below. The code below changes a person's name that is entered in the textfield and when user clicks on cancel button it will put the old name back  into the textfield. But for some reason a magic happens and whenever I set the person's name it overwrites the field in the cancelPerson variable. Could not figure out why this would happen? I get the cancelPerson from persons list before I set the new value. So how come changes in the persons list can affect an independent variable. Any idea why this would occur? Thanks.

```
 private ObservableList<Person> persons;
 private Person person;
 private Person cancelPerson;

    personName.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (!newValue) {
                    final int index = personIdCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                    cancelPerson = persons.get(index);
                    final Person person = persons.get(index);
                    person.setName(personName.getText());
                    persons.set(index, person);
                }
            }
    );


class Person{
   private final StringProperty name;
   public Person() {

        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty("testName");           

   }

   public SystemParams(Person person) {

      this.name = person.name;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Jim Garrison's answer (suggesting the copy constructor) is correct; I
>   just wanted to add another answer to give a helpful way of thinking
>   about references in Java.

I found it helpful to think of an `=` assignment as a `REFERS TO` assignment. So, `cancelPersons = persons.get(index);` is basically saying:

```
cancelPerson REFERS TO persons.get(index);
```

Now, where your second line says `final Person person = persons.get(index);`, think of it as

`final Person person REFERS TO persons.get(index);`

See how they both REFER TO the same `persons.get(index)`? Now, whether you use `cancelPerson` or just `person`, Java is pointing back to the same overall object, not different ones.

**Unless you have a `new` keyword somewhere, you are not actually creating a new object.**

Answer (score 5):

This is because `person` and `cancelPerson` are ***references*** and when you do

```
 cancelPerson = persons.get(index);
 final Person person = persons.get(index);
```

You end up with both variables pointing to *the same object*.

If you want to save a copy of `person` you have to do a "deep copy", that is create a new `Person` and copy the contents to the new object.  This is usually done with what is referred to as a "copy constructor"

```
class Person {
    public Person() { ... the no-arg constructor }
    public Person(Person p) {
        this.name = p.name;
        ... etc
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I created my copy const. and did this.  cancelPerson=new Person(persons.get(index));     this still does the same thing affects the cancelPerson. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You would need to share the code for the constructor you wrote for us to help with that error...

Comment: I added a small portion of my class. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

In Java, class instances like instances of `Person` are reference types. This means that when you perform an assignment, you are merely copying a reference to an instance.

In your code, `person` and `cancelPerson` both refer to the same Person instance and any operations you do on them affect that same instance.

You could make a copy of a `Person` instance first if you don't want it to be modified.